# IBM Watson Assistant list_logs funct

Tags: logging, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I am trying to get the logs from Watson Assistant but the json that the list_logs function provided in the api documentation is coming back with request fields empty. it  is only capturing requests for only certain conversations.

However if we go into the Assistant tooling backend and check the logs, there all the logs are captured

The api call log_list() function I am using as in the docs:
[image: The api call log_list() function I am using as in the docs]

I am calling the API using python. I am using 'list_logs' function with parameters 'workspace id' and 'filters'.

```
from watson_developer_cloud import AssistantV1 

assistant = AssistantV1(version='2018-07-10',
                        username='apikey',
                        password='<mypassword>',
                        url='<my_url>' )
response = assistant.list_logs( 
       workspace_id='<my_workspace_id> ',
       filter="response_timestamp>"+str(date.today()-timedelta(1))   
     ).get_result()
```

The Json being returned by the above api call:
[image: The Json being returned by the above api call]

The backend logs view which shows all the inputs in the log:
[image: The backend logs view which shows all the inputs in the log]

Comment: not all request fields are empty, some of the logs are being returned, but most aren't.

Comment: Provide the details on how you call the API.

Comment: I am calling the API using python. I am using 'list_logs' function with parameters 'workspace id' and 'filters'.(it is the function in the first screenshot attached)

Comment: from watson_developer_cloud import AssistantV1
        assistant = AssistantV1(
                   version='2018-07-10',
                   username='apikey',
                   password='<mypassword>',
                   url='<my_url>'
                   )
            response = assistant.list_logs(
                   workspace_id='<my_workspace_id> ',
                   filter="response_timestamp>"+str(date.today()-timedelta(1))
                   ).get_result()

Comment: What is the result when requesting the logs without filter?

Comment: when I don't put in filters, it returns more data but still same, there are many empty response jsons. Without date filter I am getting logs from Jan 29 onwards to Feb 1st

Comment: So the programming is correct. If you have a lite plan, there are 7 days of logs. That is correct, too. Provide details about what is missing or open a support ticket.

Comment: @data_henrik thank you. I have opened a support ticket.

and on details of what is missing, so for instance not all the conversations that are logged in the assistant tooling back end is present in the response json that I get back. so for instance when I just get the logs for Feb 4th, I can see there are a lot of different inputs which were captured in the tooling backend, I dont see most of them when I open the response json (which i get using the list_logs() function)